# Should an answer be downvoted because the question is considered badly formatted?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes, english

I am referring to [this answer I gave on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389631/how-can-i-answer-the-second-question/389632#389632), but I am interested in a general answer (since I browse many SE sites).
I cannot find an existing question about this on meta. Most results I find are about questions that ask the wrong thing (e.g. the XY problem), which is not the case for these examples as far as I'm aware.

The question that was asked was understandable, although it could have done with a bit of better formatting.
However, I do believe that the OP was incapable of providing more information, as he did not understand the sentence at all. At best, he could have changed the formatting of his question which doesn't really add to the question in any functional way.

After I responded (since the question was clear), I was then told that the question did not *deserve* an answer and my answer was promptly downvoted.

[This is a second example on English.SE where I was told something similar, although I did not receive downvotes there.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389289/meaning-of-the-idiom-mutely-appreciated)

It seems unfair to punish an answer for the (aesthetic) mistakes made by a question, but I understand that I could be oblivious to an otherwise established (but seemingly unwritten) rule of SE.

Am I expected on StackExchange to only answer questions when their formatting is community approved? How can I make sure that this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to RegDwigнt, who now also deleted the post, I must take into account whether OP is eligible for the position he's applying for. And since he is not, must therefore refuse to answer his question.

I think I'm just done with all this subjective bullshit. Rules seem to just magically fit whatever the current topic is, for no discernible reason other than "we said so".

You don't need to respond anymore. I'm done. I will accept my own answer in 2 days.

Comment: Every answer I've received has somehow missed the point (stating there are two questions being asked, responding about the downvoting of the question instead of downvoting the answer, ...), yet I'm blamed for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

That's not what the comment says. It doesn't talk about the *formatting* at all.

It is saying that a question that is unclear shouldn't be answered - I tend to agree with that, as answered to an unclear question contain too many assumptions about what they think the question OP meant.

Comment: There are two questions on the image (although admittedly, the first doesn't end with a question mark). OP asks what the second question means. How is that not clear? Yes, he should have added the question as text and not just an inline image, but that does not change whether the question is understandable or not. I'm not arguing that this question needs polishing because it does, but it is not unclear.

Comment: Well, that's the problem with questions that have... multiple questions.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me here. The image that was linked contains two questions. But the _question posted to English.SE_ very clearly asks about the second question that is on the image. Not both questions. It is not a question with multiple questions.

Comment: @Flater I saw the question (before its deletion) and I thought it was clear that they were asking about the "if yes" one, not the one you were talking about. This is why it's unclear (and why I voted to close). (It could also be closed as too basic.)

Comment: @Laurel: The "If yes" is not a question though. It hadn't even crossed my mind when I wrote my answer, since there are clearly two questions contained in the image (clear to me, at the time of writing my answer). I also have no issue with the question being downvoted for the shorthand way of asking, my question here is about _downvoting the answer_.

Comment: @Flater Your view is valid—and so is mine. Even without a question mark, was it not "a sentence worded or expressed so as to elicit information" (Oxford Living Dictionary)?

Comment: @Laurel: This is what's wrong with SE rules, most notably on English.SE (as it seems to be more strictly enforced). People are so focused on being factually correct that they completely forget it's supposed to be about helping people who have a question that usually hinges on something far simpler than the skill level of those who answer and/or review.

Comment: @Laurel: A slightly more direct answer: Even if we accept that the definition of answer is broad enough to include the second entry; **does that warrant downvoting an answer**? Everyone responds about the quality of the question, but it is my assertion that **downvoting the answer** is not the right place to address issues you have with the question.